# Tabs created using jquery

Tags: java, jsp, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I created some tabs using jquery and when I am loading the main page(which contains the tabs), the main page in refreshed as many times as the number of tabs in that page....This is happening in firefox browser...How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance...

hi, 
   here is my code.....

```
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li id="planDetails-tab"><a id="hrefPlanDetailsid" accesskey="p" href="#divPlanDetailsTab" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;Plan Details</a></li>
    <li id="serviceArea-tab"><a href="#divServiceAreaTab" accesskey="s" class="planTabHeader">Service Area</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have included pages for those tabs as

```
 <s:include value="PlanDetail.jsp" />
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add some code here that you are doing..

Comment: Oh man..not here..`edit` your question and add it there with `code` formatting..